# Is there a name for the concept that is the generalisation of probability and likelihood?

Tags: probability, likelihood

Given some model parameter $\theta$ and some data $x$, the model distribution is written as $p(x\vert \theta)$ and the likelihood as $L(\theta\vert x)$. Is there some formalised more general concept $f(x, \theta)$, and if so what is it called?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean "more general concept $f(x, \theta)$". A *function* is a formal concept that is more general than the likelihood or pdf, but I don't think it's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I agree with @CliffAB , the walid answer to your question could be for example "a function", but I doubt this is what your question is about.

Answer (score 0):

In one sense, both the likelihood $L(\theta |x)$ and the distribution $f(x,\theta)$ do the same thing: they take in a value of $x$ and a value of $\theta$ and spit out a number. The distinction is in which of the inputs, $x$ or $\theta$, is considered the variable and which is considered a fixed quantity. This distinction becomes relevant when, for example, we want to differentiate the function. For example, when we do maximum likelihood estimation, we often differentiate the likelihood with respect to $\theta$ to find a local maximum.

I don't know of any meaningful "generalization" of these two concepts that is any less abstract than the notion of a function.